# syntax error near go in a script run from powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to bulk import into SQL Server, and I need to automate the task (there are thousands of directories) in Powershell. I'm using bcp and have a format file because I need to skip a column when importing. Whenever I run this, it fails with the error:

> Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

The code is:

```
$query =
"USE Database;  
 GO  
 BULK INSERT $tableName   
    FROM 'C:\users\Name\documents\bcp_sql\File\$name\$dir_id${string}.csv'   
    WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\users\Name\documents\bcp_sql\formatFile.fmt');  
    GO  
    SELECT * FROM $tableName;  
    GO"  
$sqlCmd2 = $connection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCmd2.Connection = $connection
$sqlCmd2.CommandText = $query
$sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader()
```

I've confirmed that the file paths do, in fact, exist (by cd-ing to them).

Comment: Your problem is that `go` is not an SQL Server command. It's a batch separator in Management Studio.

Comment: I copied the syntax from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-skip-a-table-column-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Any suggestions on what to do instead?

Comment: I would assume it works just fine if you leave out the `go`s. If not, you should be able to define the database also in connect string, or run a separate command in the same connection for use.

Comment: Your database should already be specified in the connection, so you don't need a `USE Database` in the first place. Remove all `GO` statements. And execute `BULK INSERT` and `SELECT` as 2 separate statements, the former via `ExecuteNonQuery()`, the latter via `ExecuteReader()`.